# Making fire effect on iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, effects

I'll describe ways that I already know, and can do, and want to hear another suggestions, or may be even solutions :)

Create N frames of fire with semi-transparent pictures (PNGs)
Like at [this site](http://flashden.net/item/fire-animation/14101)

Create pixel-based fire - line by line with shifting up. (not the best way I think)
[Like here](http://www.smartypantscoding.com/content/old-school-fire-modern-day-wpf)

Any other solutions?

Comment: You may wait until the iphone burns itself. Just advice users to overload the accumulator ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mr.doob's fire effect](http://mrdoob.com/blog/post/511) in flash is very clever.

Answer (score 1):

[Particles Fire Prototype by Nicolas Goles](http://www.vimeo.com/6652481)

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 7 of [iPhone Games Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219688) begins with a discussion of fire effects.

Answer (score 0):

A movie with the fire animation playing, or maybe an animated .gif image.